# Trying to connect postgre using docker for one of my cordapp

Tags: corda

I am following this blog to set up database environment for one of the cordapp.

https://www.corda.net/blog/cordapp-database-setup-development-perspective/

I have successfully pulled the postgre image in docker and also executed that. The container is up and also I logged in as superuser. Now, I am trying to execute the below scripts to create users using the below command but I am not sure whether it's working fine or not.

**cat party_a.sql | docker exec -i postgres_for_corda psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres**

Can anyone please share some command through which I can check whether this particular user has been created or not. If it's not created then what are the steps I need to follow?

[image: docker screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the computer is trying to run docker commands from the postgres shell (as the postgres user).

You'll need to open up a new terminal window in order to run commands as your normal user.

If you want to check if a user exists in postgres, take a look at this great cheat sheet: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cheat-sheet/

the command you're looking for is this:

```
\du
```